# Order result set based on multiple OR'd predicates

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got a situation where I need to fetch X number of records from a table based on a set criteria that have an order of precedence. In other words:

1. Try to fetch X number of records from table using criteria 1.
2. If the quota of X isn't met, try to fetch additional records from table using criteria 2.
3. If the quota of X STILL isn't met, try to fetch additional records from table using criteria 3.

A concrete example:

```
+----+-----------------+-------------------+-------------+                     
| id | primary_user_id | secondary_user_id | location_id |
+----+-----------------+-------------------+-------------+
|  1 | user1           | user1             | MI          |
|  2 | user1           | user2             | NV          |
|  3 | user2           | user1             | MI          |
|  4 | user1           | user3             | MI          |
|  5 | user4           | user5             | NV          |
+----+-----------------+-------------------+-------------+
```

- Criteria 1: `secondary_user_id = @user`
- Criteria 2: `primary_user_id = @user`
- Criteria 3: `location_id = @location`

From my understanding, a simple OR clause will not guarantee the records returned are in the same order as the criteria they were fetched with:

```
SELECT * FROM Foo WHERE
  secondary_user_id = 'user1' OR
  primary_user_id = 'user1' OR
  location_id = 'NV'
LIMIT 2
```

A UNION seems to be a better choice:

```
SELECT * FROM Foo WHERE secondary_user_id = 'user1'
UNION
SELECT * From Foo WHERE primary_user_id = 'user1'
UNION
SELECT * FROM Foo WHERE location_id = 'NV'
```

With the limit:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT * FROM Foo WHERE secondary_user_id = 'user1'
  UNION
  SELECT * From Foo WHERE primary_user_id = 'user1'
  UNION
  SELECT * FROM Foo WHERE location_id = 'NV'
) AS r LIMIT 2
```

Is UNION the only option here if I want to make sure the results are in the same order as the criteria they were fetched with? I know this could be done programmatically in my application, but I'd like to offload as much work to the database if possible (MySQL if that matters).

Comment: you can use order by in every query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use `order by`:

```
SELECT *
FROM Foo
WHERE secondary_user_id = 'user1' OR
      primary_user_id = 'user1' OR
      location_id = 'NV'
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN secondary_user_id = 'user1' THEN 1
               WHEN primary_user_id = 'user1' THEN 2
               ELSE 3
          END)
LIMIT 2;
```

Do not, I repeat *DO NOT*, assume that `UNION` or `UNION ALL` will produce results in a particular order.  The only way to guarantee an ordering is to use an explicit `ORDER BY` clause.

Answer (score 0):

Your last query looks like the best working solution for the task since you wish to keep it within MySQL.

The only problem is that `UNION` clause might give you some rows more than once. E.g., if a row has `secondary_user_id = 'user1'` and `primary_user_id = 'user1'`, it'll be returned twice.

To avoid this, use `DISTINCT`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM (
  SELECT * FROM Foo WHERE secondary_user_id = 'user1'
  UNION
  SELECT * From Foo WHERE primary_user_id = 'user1'
  UNION
  SELECT * FROM Foo WHERE location_id = 'NV'
) AS r LIMIT 2
```

**EDITED**

@ZaynulAbadinTuhin is absolutely right that

> `UNION` automatically make `DISTINCT` if two query returned same name

So the last query from the question would work just fine without any changes.

Comment: union automatically make distinct if two query returned same name @IIdar

Comment: @ZaynulAbadinTuhin oops, yes, you're absolutely right! Thanks!

Comment: then why need distinct ?

Comment: @ZaynulAbadinTuhin I'm editing my answer ) It seems that the last query from the question would work just fine without any changes.

Answer (score 0):

You could also simply use ORs and then add an ORDER BY using CASE:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM Foo 
 WHERE secondary_user_id = 'user1' 
    OR primary_user_id = 'user1' 
    OR location_id = 'NV'
 ORDER BY (CASE
               WHEN secondary_user_id = 'user1' THEN 0
               ELSE 100
           END) +
          (CASE
               WHEN primary_user_id = 'user1' THEN 0
               ELSE 10
           END) +
          (CASE
               WHEN location_id = 'NV' THEN 0
               ELSE 1
           END);
```

It's efficient, but is a bit less readable.